# How can I send a POST request in php?

Tags: php, curl, post, https

I try to send request from post type to server but it not success,
It return me BadRequest with status 400,

My code:

```
$products = array('1'=>array('amount'=>'1','product_id'=>'11250'));
$data = array('id' => '67', 'shipping' => '61', 'payment'=> '2','products'=> $products);
$cert = base64_encode('myapp@myapp.co.il:1234abcd');
$header = array(
   "authorization: Basic ".$cert,
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "cache-control: no-cache"
   );
$url = "https://myapp.co.il/api/aaa";

$curl = curl_init($url);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($response,true);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

It return me so:

array (2) {["message"] => string (51) "Bad Request: Syntax error, distorted JSON" ["status"] => int (400)}
But it returend me false

Comment: try echo json_encode($response); instead of $response = json_decode($response,true); and then dump the response.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `Content-Type` request header to `application/json`

Then you use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which is not for JSON, but a query string.

Change your headers to this:

```php
$header = [
   'authorization: Basic '.$cert,
   'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
   'cache-control: no-cache'
];
```

And skip the `http_build_query()`

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: Thank! I did it But now it do me this:array(2) { ["message"]=> string(22) "Unsupported Media Type" ["status"]=> int(415) }

Comment: And if you set it to `multipart/form-data` but skip the  `http_build_query()` (just insert the array)?

Comment: Now It display: array (2) {["message"] => string (48) "Bad Request: Unable to create invitation" ["status"] => int (400)}